# Azure IoT Explorer does not recognize the device as a IoT Plug and Play device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins

After creating an Azure IoT hub and the digital twin resource with the same DTDL model as that inputed in Azure IoT Explorer, the Explorer says device is not recognized as IoT P&P device.

DTDL Model validates with DTDLValidator
[image]

What am I missing, I checked this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-modeling-guide) as an example and can't see what's wrong?

1. Digital Twin created with same model:
   [image]

[image]

2. I add IoT Hub connection in IoT Explorer and create Device from the same model repo used to create the digital twin.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My DTDL model json file:

```html
{
    "@id": "dtmi:com:sergio:devkit;1",
    "@type": "Interface",
    "@context": [
        "dtmi:dtdl:context;2"
    ],
    "displayName": "Machine Part -v1",
    "description": "Machine Part data",
    "contents": [
        {
            "@type": "Property",
            "name": "PartId",
            "displayName": "PartId",
            "description": "The unique id of the machine part",
            "writable": true,
            "schema": "string"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Property",
            "name": "Alert",
            "displayName": "Alert",
            "description": "whether or not this machine part needs maintenance",
            "writable": true,
            "schema": "boolean"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Property",
            "name": "ledState",
            "displayName": "LED state",
            "description": "Returns the current state of the onboard LED.",
            "writable": true,
            "schema": "boolean"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "telemetryInterval",
            "description":  "The time interval of this data",
            "schema": "integer"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "Description",
            "schema": "string"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "Code",
            "schema": "integer"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "Temperature",
            "displayName": "Temperature",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "Humidity",
            "displayName": "Humidity",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "pressure",
            "displayName": "Pressure",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "magnetometerX",
            "displayName": "Magnetometer X / mgauss",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "magnetometerY",
            "displayName": "Magnetometer Y / mgauss",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "magnetometerZ",
            "displayName": "Magnetometer Z / mgauss",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "accelerometerX",
            "displayName": "Accelerometer X",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "accelerometerY",
            "displayName": "Accelerometer Y",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "accelerometerZ",
            "displayName": "Accelerometer Z",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "gyroscopeX",
            "displayName": "Gyroscope X",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "gyroscopeY",
            "displayName": "Gyroscope Y",
            "schema": "double"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Telemetry",
            "name": "gyroscopeZ",
            "displayName": "Gyroscope Z",
            "schema": "double"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTDL model is correct. The problem is that the device *modelId* property in the device twin doesn't exist and [must](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-ansi-c#model-id-announcement) be populated during the device connection to the IoT Hub.

The following screen snippets shows that your DTDL is working in the Azure IoT Explorer:

1. your case, where the device twin doesn't have a *modelId* property:

[image]

2. The following picture shows, that the device has assigned a modelId:

[image]

3. Now, we can see that the device *mymxchip* is modelled based on the DTDL model (modelId):

[image]

4. The following picture shows an example of the writable properties:

[image]

5. For this demonstration has been used my [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester) to allow me creating a virtual PnP device with a MQTT direct protocol to the Azure IoT Hub and simulate telemetry data, properties, commands, etc. based on the DTDL model:

[image]

The last below picture shows a modelId property in the device twin on the portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Roman Kiss , cool tool ! Your comments helped me look through the hardcoded model id value in the example i'm using, found it at nx_client.h set model_id for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-devkit-mxchip-az3166-iot-hub