# Azure IoT Explorer not connect with IoT Plug and Play componentes - Your device is not recognized as a IoT Plug and Play device

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

After creating an Azure IoT hub and the digital twin resource with the same DTDL model as that inputed in Azure IoT Explorer, the Explorer says device is not recognized as IoT P&P device.

[image]

I have read the post [Azure IoT Explorer does not recognize the device as a IoT Plug and Play device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815008/azure-iot-explorer-does-not-recognize-the-device-as-a-iot-plug-and-play-device)

But I don't understand where I can find IoT Plug and Resize

Comment: The problem is that the device modelId property in the device twin doesn't exist and must be populated during the device connection to the IoT Hub.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the IoT Plug and Play components with file `Json` in the folder (or) URL. I used `Json` [file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp#model-id-announcement).

[image]

**Used this below Reference:**

- Send telemetry from an IoT Plug and Play device to Azure IoT [Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-iot-hub?toc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-hub%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-hub%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&pivots=programming-language-csharp)
- IoT Plug and Play service developer [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-developer-guide-service?pivots=programming-language-csharp).

[image]

- The code reference is taken from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp#model-id-announcement).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]